# xcode 7.2 (cordova) clang: error: linker command failed with exit code (how to troubleshoot)

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode7, cordova-plugins

I am trying to troubleshoot this annoying error.
I have a cordova project which was working fine up until changed the name of the app (took out spaces) in the XCode general panel. After that (it seemed to work fine) I removed and reinstalled a plugin (LocalNotifications). Then I started getting all kinds of errors in the build process - libraries not found and other errors I don't recall immediately.
Then:

- I removed the ios platform via CLI and added it again.
- I manually moved all the SDKs back into Frameworks, etc.
- I deleted derived data
- I cleaned the xcode project quit xcode and relaunched

After all that (twice) I am consistently getting the error in build:

```
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I noticed it always happens after a certain plugin is loaded. I was trying to figure out where XCode is finding the duplicate method (symbol) by looking at the error log. When I go into build phases and reorder the linked libraries that doesn't seem to influence the order in which they're compiled in the build process.

My questions are:

- how do I narrow down where the duplicate symbol is ?
- does it matter the order of the linked libraries in Build Phases?
- could my renaming of the app be a factor here?

I seem to recall this happening before and I found there was some duplicate files left over from uninstalling plugins. However I have removed and added the IOS platform so that should rule out any duplicates?